# XSLT 1.0: rearrange xml in different steps(xsl-template)

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to rearrange an XML in multiple steps by using different xsl-templates and have managed to make it working - with 2 separated xsl transformation in sequence.  I am currently struggling to put the 2 xsl files into one but failed. To achieve this: Is there a way to use the result of one template in another template?

Source XML:

```
<order>
    <header/>
    <items>
        <item no="001" material="5001" qty="4"/>
        <item no="002" material="5002" qty="5"/>
        <item no="P000" material="box" qty="2"/>
        <item no="P001" origin_no="001" material="5001" batch="L01" qty="1"/>
        <item no="P002" origin_no="001" material="5001" batch="L02" qty="3"/>
    </items>
    <packages>
        <package id="U01">
            <content item_no="P001" qty="1"/>
            <content item_no="002" qty="2"/>
        </package>
        <package id="U02">
            <content item_no="P002" qty="3"/>
            <content item_no="002" qty="2"/>
        </package>
        <package id="U03">
            <content item_no="002" qty="1"/>
        </package>
    </packages>
    <summery/>
</order>
```

This XML contains a delivery order with 2 line items and shipping packages. The 3. line item with number "P000" is the packing aid material. The 4. and 5. line items are the two batches splitting from the 1. line item. 
The reference between normal line item and its batch splits is the attribute "origin_no".

The task is, according to which package has the content of which line item, the package segment is to put underneath the relevant item. In case of batch splits: the package segments need to be put under the origin item but not the batch item.

The result needs to be as following:

```
<order>
    <header/>
    <items>
        <item no="001" material="5001" qty="4">
            <package id="U01" item_no="P001" qty="1" origin_item_no="001" batch="L01"/>
            <package id="U02" item_no="P002" qty="3" origin_item_no="001" batch="L02"/>
        </item>
        <item no="002" material="5002" qty="5">
            <package id="U01" item_no="002" qty="2"/>
            <package id="U02" item_no="002" qty="2"/>
            <package id="U03" item_no="002" qty="1"/>
        </item>
    </items>
    <summery/>
</order>
```

By running following 2 xsl in sequence I could get the result successfully. My questions would be: is there an elegant way to achieve this requirement in one single XSLT mapping without using the extention "exsl:node-set"(which I have learned from other posts)?

First XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="package/content">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="v_item_no_package" select="@item_no"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="../../../items/item[@no = $v_item_no_package]">
                <xsl:attribute name="origin_item_no"><xsl:value-of select="@origin_no"/></xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="batch"><xsl:value-of select="@batch"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Second XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            <xsl:variable name="v_no_item" select="@no"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="../../packages/package/content[@origin_item_no = $v_no_item]">
                <xsl:element name="package">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../@id"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="./* | @*[not(.='')]"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="../../packages/package/content[@item_no = $v_no_item]">
                <xsl:element name="package">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../@id"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="./* | @*[not(.='')]"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="packages">
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="items/item[starts-with(@no, 'P')]">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks a lot and greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have two transformation steps in a single stylesheet then you need to use modes https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#modes and additionally with XSLT 1 you need to use an extension function like `exsl:node-set` as the result of one transformation step is a result tree fragment and to push that through the second step you need to convert it to a node-set first. So there you have one way to approach that, although for some reason you seem to want to avoid `exsl:node-set`.

If you are looking to implement your requirement in a different way then you need to eliminate the addition of the attributes on the content and instead try to collect and transform them directly, additionally to handle the various references it is useful to use keys:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:key name="content-ref" match="package/content" use="@item_no"/>
    <xsl:key name="p-item-ref" match="items/item" use="@origin_no"/>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('content-ref', @no)"/>

            <xsl:variable name="referenced-items" select="key('p-item-ref', @no)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$referenced-items">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('content-ref', @no)">
                    <xsl:with-param name="atts" select="@batch | @origin_no"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>                 
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="packages">
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="items/item[starts-with(@no, 'P')]">
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="package/content">
        <xsl:param name="atts" select="/.."/>
        <package id="{../@id}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*[normalize-space()] | $atts"/>
        </package>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@origin_no">
        <xsl:attribute name="origin_item_no">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online sample at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTu/3 which I think does the job.

Comment: wow this is so great and would be exactly the alternative solution I needed. Thank you very much for your help.